# определить сложность алгоритма программы поиска в ширину в графе

Tags: python, алгоритм

есть необходимость определить сложность алгоритма программы

```
Graph = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

# список смежности
list = [[j for j in range(len(Graph[i]))
         if Graph[i][j] != 0]
        for i in range(len(Graph))]
print(list)

def search(graph, v):
    visited = {v}
    no_visited = [v]
    while no_visited:
        data = no_visited.pop(0)
        print(name[data], data)
        data_new = [i for i in graph[data] if i not in visited]
        no_visited.extend(data_new)
        visited.update(data_new)

search(list, 0)
```

Comment: в википедии же даже это написано https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83

Comment: мне нужно оценить сложность разработанной моей программы

Comment: @Женя Ермолаев Она не имеет отношения к описанному везде алгоритму BFS?